# Turning Preordered Sets into Preordered Monoids (Constructing Preordered Monoids from Preordered Sets)

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, category-theory, order-theory

**Question:**

Referring to the Wikipedia article on [Adjoint Functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) in Section [2 (Motivation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors#Motivation), they talk about "turning rngs into rings" (can be rephrased as "constructing rings from rngs").  I do not quite understand how this "turning" of algebraic structures into new algebraic structures is done. Which brings up my main question: knowing this method of turning structures into new structures, can we do the same with turning preordered sets into preordered monoids? Can we do the same with turning either structure into preordered *free* monoids?

**Background:**

*Definition (Preordered Monoid).* A quadruple $\mathcal{X}=(X,\sqsubseteq,\cdot,e)$ such that

- $\sqsubseteq$ preorders $X$,
- $(X,\cdot,e)$ is a monoid,
- for all $x\in X, \ e\sqsubseteq x$, and
- (for all $w,x,y,z\in X$) if $w\sqsubseteq x$ and $y\sqsubseteq x$, then $w\cdot y\sqsubseteq x\cdot z$.

Comment: In many concrete categories there will be a construction of "free objects" possessing certain universal mapping properties.  I see no reason why one might not pursue an attack on "turning preordered sets into preordered monoids" along that line.  However you've only sketched an idea by analogy that leaves much to the Readers' imaginations.  I suggest self-deleting your Question until you've been able to edit it into better shape.  See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not possible to extend a given preorder $(X, \sqsubseteq)$ to a preordered monoid $(X, \sqsubseteq, \cdot, e)$:

Consider any preorder $(X, \sqsubseteq)$ such that for all $x \in X$ there is some $y \in X$ with $y \sqsubseteq x$ and $x \not \sqsubseteq y$. [For example $(\mathbb Z, \le)$]. Then there is no $e \in X$ such that $e \sqsubseteq x$ for all $x \in X$ and therefore, $(X, \sqsubseteq)$ cannot be extended to a preordered monoid $(X, \sqsubseteq, \cdot, e)$ without changing $\sqsubseteq$.

On the other hand, if $(X, \sqsubseteq)$ contains an element $e \in X$ such that $e \sqsubseteq x$ for all $x \in X$, we may let $\cdot \colon X \times X \to X, x \mapsto e$ be the trivial multiplication which yields a preordered monoid $(X, \sqsubseteq, \cdot, e)$ as desired.

I'm not sure what you mean by a *free* preorderd monoid in this setting, but if you provide your definition, I might be able to add an answer to that last part of your question as well.

Comment: I think we are considering the empty element $e\in X$. Basically it is a preordered _free monoid_ such that if we define $X$ to be a set, then the _free monoid_ $X^*$ is the set of all strings over $X$. Then we make it preordered. My bad. I think that if I switched "free" and "preordered," it would have made more sense.

Comment: @Julian But now you are talking about different structures. Given a preorder $(X, \sqsubseteq)$ it may not be the case that $X = X^*$ (where the latter is the set of finite string over the alphabet $X$) and in this case, we are left with a set $X^*$ - without a preorder. So in which sense do you want to carry the preorder on $X$ over to $X^*$ and in which sense would you like it to be compatible with its structure as a monoid?

Comment: I would like the preorder to carry over to $X^*$. What "senses" for compatability are there?

Comment: @JulianRachman, you just take $\gtrsim_{X^*}$ as the least monoid-compatible preorder on $X^*$ such that for all $x,y \in X$, we have $$y \gtrsim_{X} x \rightarrow y \gtrsim_{X^*} x.$$ By monoid-compatible, I mean: $$y' \gtrsim y \wedge x' \gtrsim x \rightarrow y'x' \gtrsim yx.$$

Comment: @goblin Can you write a full answer? I want to see the whole process leading up to this result.

Comment: @JulianRachman, I'm quite busy at the moment, but I'll see what I can throw together a bit later.

Comment: @goblin Thank you. I await your response.

Comment: @Stefan ${}{}{}$ ^

Comment: @goblin ${}{}{}$ ^

Comment: @Julian While I recognize your reminder, I'm still not sure what your question regarding the free monoid is. Is it a) Can any free monoid be preordered? (Which is trivially true.) or b) Can we carry over the preorder on $X$ to gain a preorderered monoid on $X^*$? (Well, yes. But the answer depends on how exactly you want to relate the preorders on $X$ and $X^*$. So in order to give an answer to this question, you should provide us with the preorder on $X^*$.)

Comment: @Stefan Then let's define this: let us define a well-quasi-order (wqo) on $X$. Then we may define the subword (domination) order on $X^*$.

Comment: @Julian In this case it is easy to see that $(X^*, \preceq, \cdot, e)$ is always a preordered monoid, where $\preceq$ is the subword order obtained from $\sqsubseteq$, $\cdot$ is concatenation and $e$ is the empty word.

Comment: Ok. I don't want to ask you for too much but, would you be able to give me a full work out of turning a preordered set into a preordered monoid? And maybe into a preordered free monoid?

Comment: Wait. So I am wondering how this pertains to adjoint functors.

Comment: @Julian Let $(X, \sqsubseteq)$ be a preorder. Let $X^*$ be the set of finite words over the alphabet $X$ and let $x \cdot y$ be the concatenation of $x$ and $y$. Let $e$ be the empty word and for $x = x_1 \ldots x_m, y= y_1 \ldots y_n \in X^*$ let $x \preceq y$ iff there is a subword $y_{i_1} \ldots y_{i_m}$ in $y$ such that $x_j \sqsubseteq y_j$ for $j=1, \ldots, n$. It's now trivial to check that $(X^*, \preceq, \cdot, e)$ is a preordered monoid.

Comment: By adjoint functors?

Comment: @Julian I suggest you try to figure out which question you actually want to ask and then consider opening a new post. At this point your request deviates quite a bit from your initial question.

Comment: My question is exactly the same. I am about adjoint functors above.

Comment: Apologies for joining the discussion uninvited. But I just wanted to add a similar construction I found to @StefanMesken's three comments above. 
Keeping in mind that we can always decategorify a category **C** into a preorder **P** by saying $a \preceq b$ whenever $\exists \ a \rightarrow b \in Mor(\mathbf{C})$ Stephan's construction is identical to the *free construction of strict monoidal category from a category* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category#Free_strict_monoidal_category on Wikipedia.
Thank you both for this discussion, it's been very useful.